# Inserting interval into a collection

Tags: c#, collections, interval

The task is fairly simple. I want to create a collection of intervals and implement an `Add` method which would insert new intervals to the collection and merge overlapping ones. I would also like this method to somehow tell me which parts of the added interval were not in the collection before adding.

Here is an interval implementation, which is pretty straightforward:

```
public class Interval
{
    public Interval(int start, int end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public Interval ()
    {
    }

    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }

    public bool Contains(int value)
    {
        return value <= End && value >= Start;
    }

    public bool Contains(Interval other)
    {
        return Contains(other.Start) && Contains(other.End);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("[{0}, {1}]", Start, End);
    }

    public Interval Clone()
    {
        return new Interval(Start, End);
    }
}
```

Implementing the collection proved to be a much trickier task.

```
public class IntervalCollection
{
    private readonly List<Interval> _intervals = new List<Interval>();

    public IEnumerable<Interval> Intervals { get { return _intervals; } }

    public bool TryAdd(Interval interval, out List<Interval> addedSections)
    {
        addedSections = null;
        int indexToDelete = -1;
        int countToDelete = 0;
        Interval mergedInterval = null;
        var i = 0;
        //in this loop i am trying to locate intersections with existing intervals
        for (; i < _intervals.Count; i++)
        {
            var current = _intervals[i];

            if (current.End < interval.Start)
            {
                //no need to inspect this one
                continue;
            }

            if (mergedInterval == null)
            {
                //start of intersection is not yet detected

                if (current.Contains(interval))
                {
                    //there is nothing to add
                    return false;
                }
                if (current.Start > interval.Start)
                {
                    //start of added interval does not intersects with anything
                    mergedInterval = new Interval(interval.Start, -1);
                    addedSections = new List<Interval> { mergedInterval.Clone() };
                    indexToDelete = i;
                }
                else if (current.Contains(interval.Start))
                {
                    //start of added interval intersects with one of the existing intervals
                    mergedInterval = new Interval(current.Start, -1);
                    addedSections = new List<Interval> {new Interval(current.End, -1) };
                    indexToDelete = i;
                }
            }

            if (mergedInterval != null)
            {
                //start of intersection is detected

                if (interval.Contains(current))
                {
                    //added interval contains current interval
                    addedSections.Last().End = current.Start;
                    addedSections.Add(new Interval(current.End, -1));
                    continue;
                }

                if (current.Contains(interval.End))
                {
                    //end of added interval intersects with one of the existing intervals
                    countToDelete = i - indexToDelete + 1;
                    addedSections.Last().End = current.Start;
                    mergedInterval.End = current.End;
                    break;
                }

                if (current.Start > interval.End)
                {
                    //no need to search further
                    countToDelete = i - indexToDelete;
                    addedSections.Last().End = mergedInterval.End = interval.End;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (mergedInterval == null)
        {
            //nothing to merge and no insert is needed, adding interval to the end
            _intervals.Add(interval);
            addedSections = new List<Interval> { interval };
            return true;
        }

        if (i == _intervals.Count)
        {
            //end of collection reached, closing open intervals
            countToDelete = i - indexToDelete;
            addedSections.Last().End = mergedInterval.End = interval.End;
        }

        //finally i am removing intervals which were merged and adding the new one instead
        _intervals.RemoveRange(indexToDelete, countToDelete);
        _intervals.Insert(indexToDelete, mergedInterval);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now if this code was not mine, I would have a really hard time figuring out what is going on in `TryAdd`. However, it seems that I fail to come up with a more readable solution. The only one I came up with involved recreating inner collection on each add, and that I do not want to do. Can someone suggest a refactoring which will improve readability of this method?  General code review is also welcome.

Comment: Does performance matter? In other words, is going through all intervals for each insert okay, or do you need something better than that?

Comment: @svick, Performance does matter to some extent, but i think, that iterating through collection is unavoidable either way. The only optimization i can think of is using binary search to find the range of intervals for merge straight away instead of iterating, but i think such optimization is premature. At the moment my main concern is readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often times readability and optimization go hand in hand.  Personally I like to enhance readability after I get reasonable optimization so that any further changes don't require re-enhancing the readability again.  Here's some code to look at.

When there are a lot of conditions to check I find that returning from the inner condition rather that nesting everything makes your code more stream line and in many case more readable.

One thing to consider using the FindIndex method the list to find the insertion point of the new interval simplifies the code quite a bit.

I added some private methods that also enhance readability by putting a logical name to blocks of code.

I implemented an IEnumerable with indexing, not sure how proper that is but it seems to work well.  Because the inner collection is a List implementing any of the List methods and/or properties should be pretty straight forward, for instance I added a Remove method.

```
public class Interval
{
    public Interval(int _start, int _end)
    {
        if(!Verify(_start, _end))
            throw new ArgumentException("Start must be less than End");
        start = _start;
        end = _end;
    }
    public Interval()
    {
        start = int.MinValue;
        end = int.MinValue + 2;
    }
    public Interval(Interval input)
    {
        start = input.start;
        end = input.end;
    }
    private bool Verify(int _start, int _end)
    {
        return (_start <= _end);
    }
    public int start
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int end
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void NewValues(Interval input)
    {
        start = input.start;
        end = input.end;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("[{0} - {1}]", start, end);
    }
}
public class IntervalCollection : IEnumerable<Interval>
{
    private readonly List<Interval> items = new List<Interval>();

    public Interval this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if(index < 0 || index >= items.Count())
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index is out of range");
            return items[index];
        }
        set
        {
            items[index] = value;
        }
    }
    public void Remove(Interval input)
    {
        if(items.Contains(input))
            items.Remove(input);
    }
    public void AddInterval(Interval input)
    {
        //if there is an existing interval that equal the new one do nothing
        if(items.Contains(input))
            return;
        //empty collection add the new one
        if(items.Count() == 0)
        {
            items.Add(input);
            return;
        }
        //if input.Start is greater than the last interval's end, we just add it.
        if(input.start > items.Last().end)
        {
            items.Add(input);
            return;
        }
        //input.End is less than the first start insert the new interval
        if(input.end < items.First().start)
        {
            items.Insert(0, input);
            return;
        }
        //find where the new interval belongs.
        Interval lesserinterval = new Interval();
        int insertionindex = items.FindIndex(ival => input.start <= ival.start);
        //All the conditions are based on the new interval(input) and the existing interval right before where the new interval belongs in the list(lesserinterval)
        if(insertionindex == 0)
        {
            //Swap the 2 so that the interval being inserted/merged is between 2 existing intervals.
            SwapIntervals(items[0], input);
            lesserinterval = items[0];
            insertionindex++;
        }
        else
            //if FindIndex doesn't find a suitable insertion point then lesserinterval is the last one
            //otherwise lesserinterval is the one at insertionindex -1
            if(insertionindex == -1)
            {
                lesserinterval = items.Last();
            }
            else
                lesserinterval = items[insertionindex - 1];
        //At this point input.Start > lesserinterval.Start
        //If it's less than or equal to lesserinterval.End, we have overlap and we merge it to lesserinterval then see if any of the rest of the intervals need to be merged.
        if(input.start <= lesserinterval.end)
        {
            if(input.end > lesserinterval.end)
            {
                lesserinterval.end = input.end;
                MergeIntervals(lesserinterval, insertionindex);
                return ;
            }
        }
        //At this point input.Start is greater than lesserinterval.End so we insert it and check the rest of the intervals to see if any need to merge into it.
        if(insertionindex != -1)
        {
            items.Insert(insertionindex, input);
            MergeIntervals(items[insertionindex], insertionindex + 1);
            return ;
        }
        if(input.end > items.Last().end)
        {
            items.Last().end = input.end;
            return ;
        }            
    }
    private void SwapIntervals(Interval a, Interval b)
    {
        Interval temp = new Interval(a);
        a.NewValues(b);
        b.NewValues(temp);
    }
    private void MergeIntervals(Interval lesser, int insertionindex)
    {
        while(lesser != items.Last())
        {
            if(lesser.end >= items[insertionindex].end)
            {
                items.RemoveAt(insertionindex);
            }
            else
                if(lesser.end >= items[insertionindex].start)
                {
                    lesser.end = items[insertionindex].end;
                    items.RemoveAt(insertionindex);
                    return;
                }
                else
                    return;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator<Interval> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new MyEnumerator(this);
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    // Declare the enumerator and implement the IEnumerator interface:
    public class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator<Interval>
    {
        int nIndex;
        IntervalCollection collection;
        public void Dispose()
        {
            collection = null;
        }
        public MyEnumerator(IntervalCollection coll)
        {
            collection = coll;
            nIndex = -1;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            nIndex = -1;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            nIndex++;
            return (nIndex < collection.items.Count());
        }

        public Interval Current
        {
            get
            {
                return (collection.items[nIndex]);
            }
        }

        // The current property on the IEnumerator interface:
        object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return (Current);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unless necessary you should consider making your `Interval` immutable by making the `set`s private. It's easier to deal with such "value containers" if they're immutable (see `Point`, `DateTime`, etc.).

Also at the moment you can break your collection by doing the following (also it's non obvious what happens, to be honest):

```
List<Interval> intervals = new List<Interval>();
IntervalCollection intervalsCollection = new IntervalCollection();
intervalsCollection.TryAdd(new Interval(1, 5), out intervals);
intervalsCollection.TryAdd(new Interval(20, 25), out intervals);
intervalsCollection.TryAdd(new Interval(7, 10), out intervals);

Interval intervalA = new Interval(100, 120);
intervalsCollection.TryAdd(intervalA, out intervals)
intervalA.Start = 7;
intervalA.End = 50;
```

Prints:

```
[1, 5]
[7, 10]
[20, 25]
[7, 50]
```

---

This class would benefit *a lot* from documentation. F.e. it is not obvious if the start or end is inclusive or exclusive. Make sure to cover this in the docs.

---

Adding an `Intersects` function would also help in the long run, especially when checking in the list.

```
foreach (Interval interval : theIntervalsYouHave)
{
    if (interval.Intersects(intervalToInsert))
    {
        // ...
```

An `Extend` function might also be interesting for later use, something like this:

```
function Interval Extend(Interval extendWith)
{
    return new Interval(
        Math.Min(Start, extendWith.Start),
        Math.Max(End, extendWith.End));
}
```

---

There's no checking if `Start` is greater then `End`, is this a valid `Interval`?

```
new Interval(10, 5);
```

---

```
var i = 0;
//in this loop i am trying to locate intersections with existing intervals
for (; i < _intervals.Count; i++)
{
```

You did not reuse `i` for something different then the loop counter, did you? That's bad, either rename it accordingly or use a different variable for whatever you need to do outside of the loop.

---

The name `IntervalsCollection` suggests that it implements `ICollection` or `Icollection<Interval>` (or inherits from one of the implementing classes), yet this is not the case. Either rename the class or actually implement `ICollection`...or clearly document why this is not the case.

---

If I see this correct, `IntervalsCollection.TryAdd()` does not really try to add an interval, it will add it, merge it with another or not add it.

Without knowing your exact usage, maybe a better approach would be to provide a immutable collection which needs to be recreated every time.

1. You make `Interval` immutable.
2. You write an implementation of `ICollection<Interval>` (called `Intervals`, there might be a better name) which is readonly.
3. You create a static constructor/factory function `Merge` which accepts the original collection and a new value to add to it and returns a new collection. You can add overloads as you see fit (f.e. one that only accepts `Interval`s without a prior collection).

That twill leave you with a very slick interface (and much less glue), which looks like this:

```
Intervals intervals = Intervals.Merge(intervalA, intervalB, intervalC);
Intervals extended = Intervals.Merge(intervals, intervalD);
```

And no way to break the list.

Comment: He actually does use `i` later on, but great advice to rename it. Possibly something like `intervalsChecked` based on its usage. Anyway, great answer!

Answer (score 4):

I wish I had a suggestion on how to improve your loop, but as you said, it's much trickier than you might think, and I'm probably not smart enough. ;-)

Only suggestions I can think of here:

- Your code like `new Interval(current.Start, -1)` really bothers me. I'd suggest adding another constructor like the following since the 2nd parameter doesn't matter in each of those calls:

  ```
  public Interval(int point)
  {
    Start = point;
    End = point;
  }
  ```

  you could now call `new Interval(current.Start);` which feels cleaner to me.
- If you add that constructor, you can also update your other one to accept the start and end values swapped. Personally, when I think of an interval the order of the start and end doesn't matter to me. I.E. 2,4 and 4,2 are the same. Your code can't handle the latter properly. An example to correct that follows:

  ```
  public Interval(int start, int end)
  {
    if (start > end) // parameters swapped
    {
      Start = end;
      End = start;
    }
    else
    {
      Start = start;
      End = end;
    }
  }
  ```
- Consider changing `return value <= End && value >= Start;` to

  `return Start <= value && value <= End;` for slightly improved readability. I find the 2nd format easier to quickly understand.
- Possibly add some sort of comment to explain that the `List<Interval>` remains ordered by `Start` and `End` throughout the process. That's the one thing I figured out while reviewing it that made it much easier to understand why you did what you did, and how it worked.

For reference, here's the code I used to find that your program doesn't handle intervals the way I would expect. Add a break point at the commented lines and inspect your locals to see what I mean:

```
IntervalCollection ic = new IntervalCollection();
List<Interval> addedIntervals = null;
ic.TryAdd(new Interval(-2, -5), out addedIntervals);
ic.TryAdd(new Interval(10, 0), out addedIntervals);
ic.TryAdd(new Interval(-4, 0), out addedIntervals);
ic.TryAdd(new Interval(-10, -5), out addedIntervals); // uh oh
ic.TryAdd(new Interval(2, 2), out addedIntervals);
ic.TryAdd(new Interval(0, -10), out addedIntervals); // uh oh
ic.TryAdd(new Interval(-3, -4), out addedIntervals);
```